# ¿Como generar un array con valores sin que estos queden dentro de un subarray de indice 0 en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Con este codigo:

```
$template["letras"][] = $letras;
$template["animales"][] = $animales;

$template = array(
    "letras" => array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3), //sin comillas al cierre
    "animales" => array("leon"=>1, "vaca"=>2, "cabra"=>3)
    );

foreach ($template as $features => $features_value) {
    ${$features."_inner"} = $features_value;
}
```

**Me genera un array asi:**

```
$letras_inner = array(0 => $features_value);
// $letras_inner = array(0 => array(3) => array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3))
```

**Espero obtener esto:**

```
$letras_inner_inner = $features_value;
// $letras_inner = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3))
```

*¿Como puedo hacer para que el array que se asigna no se convierta en un subarray de indice cero, sino que se guarde directamente?*

Comment: en php los arrays se asignan por copia, podes simplemente intentar hacer lo siguiente `$letras_inner = $features_value;`

Comment: @Sacha eso es lo que estoy haciendo, cada loop se genera una nueva variable, la cual primero se llama $letras_inner, luego $animales_inner y asi.
Lo asigno pero sale que es un indice 0

Comment: @vaavDev es extraño porque el código que escribes hace lo que quieres lograr, acá un sandbox con la prueba, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/247f77334668b58e74761365dfc3018b5c7d0a80, solo le quite algunos " que estaban de mas.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré dejame revisar, si es extraño la verdad

Comment: @LeonardoCabré agregue como obtengo mi valor de "letras" y de "animales" para llenar el array "template", leyendo lo que decia Sacha, pues elimine esos corchetes y funciono, ya guarda sin crear otro array

Comment: Me alegra que hayas podido solucionarlo!

Comment: @LeonardoCabré gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el sandbox que publica @LeonardoCabré en los comentarios de mi pregunta, observe que el codigo funciona correctamente.

Decidi revisar bien $features_value y este era el que se estaba obteniendo como un array de indice 0 y correspondiente a ese indice el valor del array.

Revise el codigo donde obtengo el valor de $letras y $animales y estaba creando un array donde era una variable normal, esto lo revise pensando en el comentario de Sasha sobre el copiado de variables en PHP.

El codigo quedo asi:

```
$template["letras"] = $letras;
// Sin corchetes

$template["animales"] = $animales;
// Sin corchetes

$template = array(
    "letras" => array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3), //sin comillas al cierre
    "animales" => array("leon"=>1, "vaca"=>2, "cabra"=>3)
    );

foreach ($template as $features => $features_value) {
    ${$features."_inner"} = $features_value;
}
```